# Prove that if $F$ is a finite field having q elements, then $a^{q-2}=a^{-1}$ for a nonzero $a \in F$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

This is a proposition from J.S.Golan's "The Linear Algebra a beginning graduate student ought to know".

I can't understand why it's so.
Obviously, the order of $a$ is finite - higher than $1$ and lower than $q+1$.
But what next?

Comment: this is a consequence of fermats little theorem.

Comment: @Brennan.Tobias Fermat's little theorem concerns primes, not prime powers...

Answer (score 3):

If we can apply some group theory: there are $q-1$ units in the field (all non-zero elements), and these units form a group under multiplication.  Applying Lagrange's theorem, we see that $a^{q-1} = 1$ for every $a \neq 0$.  Now, $a^{q-2} = a^{q-1-1}$, so...

Comment: @Servaes I'm leaving out the very last step.

Comment: @Servaes You don't need at any point cyclicity of the group of units.

Comment: It is *not* necessary to prove that the group is cyclic

Comment: @Bernard You are right, I misunderstood the question. I removed my irrelevant comments.